# Has a public version of Red Star OS Version 4.0 been released?

Tags: iso, download

It is reported that [Red Star OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Star_OS)'s latest version is 4.0. Does anyone happen to have a copy of this operating system or ISO? I can see from the headers of "http://www.airkoryo.com.kp/" that it's being used (as identified by wikipedia),

```
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (RedStar4.0)
```

Comment: Last I heard, it was in sorta beta internal usage. The latest I've been able to find was 3, but I'd be very interested to check out 4 if anyone does have it.

Comment: Apparently South Korean media got access? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Star_OS#Version_4.0